# Successfully deploy android apk with enabled address sanitizers

Tags: android, debugging, apk, address-sanitizer

1. I´m building my apk according to https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/asan
2. My native libs are build with asan enabled (they link to `libclang_rt.asan-<arch>-android.so`
3. The `libclang_rt.asan-<arch>-android.so` is in `app/src/main/jniLibs/<arch>`
4. `wrap.sh` is in `app/src/main/resources/<arch>`
5. When installing the `apk` with `adb`: `adb: failed to install ./app/build/outputs/apk/sanitizers/app-dev-universal-sanitizers.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-2]`

As soon as I remove `wrap.sh` I can install the `apk`.
What could be missing here?

- Already checked file permissions (have `rwxr-xr-x`)
- Tried on android 8.1 up to 10

Comment: Ok, found a solution: Remove the `wrap.sh` script altogether and set the required environment variables using `android.system.Os.setenv` in java before loading the native library.

Answer (score 4):

Try add `android:extractNativeLibs="true"` in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the exact same problem on mine.